# Can't add tracing functionality in Redux with Next.js

Tags: javascript, redux, redux-devtools, redux-toolkit, redux-devtools-extension

I'd like to add the [tracing functionality](https://github.com/zalmoxisus/redux-devtools-extension/commit/64717bb9b3534ff616d9db56c2be680627c7b09d) to my dev tools in Redux:

However I when doing this:

```
export default () => {
  let store;
  const isClient = typeof window !== 'undefined';
  if (isClient) {
    const { persistReducer } = require('redux-persist');
    const storage = require('redux-persist/lib/storage').default;
    const persistConfig = {
      key: 'root',
      storage,
      stateReconciler: autoMergeLevel2,

      whitelist: ['users', 'ui'] // place to select which state you want to persist
    };

   ******composeEnhancers******

    var composeEnhancers =
      typeof window === 'object' && window.__REDUX_DEVTOOLS_EXTENSION_COMPOSE__
        ? window.__REDUX_DEVTOOLS_EXTENSION_COMPOSE__({
            // Specify extension’s options like name, actionsBlacklist, actionsCreators, serialize...
          })
        : compose;

    composeEnhancers = composeWithDevTools({
      actionCreators,
      trace: true,
      traceLimit: 25
    });

    store = createStore(
      persistReducer(persistConfig, rootReducer),
      composeEnhancers(
        applyMiddleware(thunkMiddleware, createLogger({ collapsed: false }))
      )
    );

  ******composeEnhancers******

    store.__PERSISTOR = persistStore(store);
  } else {
    store = createStore(
      rootReducer,
      composeEnhancers(
        applyMiddleware(thunkMiddleware, createLogger({ collapsed: false }))
      )
    );
  }
  return store;
};
```

I get the following error...

```
Unhandled Runtime Error
TypeError: composeEnhancers is not a function

Call Stack
module.exports../store/index.js.__webpack_exports__.default
file:///Users/antonio-pavicevac-ortiz/Dropbox/developer_folder/hillfinder/.next/server/static/development/pages/_app.js (499:84)
createStore
file:///Users/antonio-pavicevac-ortiz/Dropbox/developer_folder/hillfinder/node_modules/next-redux-wrapper/lib/index.js (95:20)
initStore
file:///Users/antonio-pavicevac-ortiz/Dropbox/developer_folder/hillfinder/node_modules/next-redux-wrapper/lib/index.js (98:20)
Object.<anonymous>
file:///Users/antonio-pavicevac-ortiz/Dropbox/developer_folder/hillfinder/node_modules/next-redux-wrapper/lib/index.js (137:33)
step
file:///Users/antonio-pavicevac-ortiz/Dropbox/developer_folder/hillfinder/node_modules/next-redux-wrapper/lib/index.js (56:23)
Object.next
file:///Users/antonio-pavicevac-ortiz/Dropbox/developer_folder/hillfinder/node_modules/next-redux-wrapper/lib/index.js (37:53)
<unknown>
file:///Users/antonio-pavicevac-ortiz/Dropbox/developer_folder/hillfinder/node_modules/next-redux-wrapper/lib/index.js (31:71)
new Promise
<anonymous>
```

Thanks in advance!

**UPDATE**

Followed a thread from [redux-toolkit](https://github.com/reduxjs/redux-toolkit/issues/121) and I think I am halfway there,
but now I am getting the following which seems odd considering my setup:

```
Error: "reducer" is a required argument, and must be a function or an object of functions that can be passed to combineReducers
```

This is my updated store:

```
import { combineReducers } from 'redux';
import { configureStore } from '@reduxjs/toolkit';
import { createLogger } from 'redux-logger';

/* imported reducers */
import ui from './reducers/ui/index';
import users from './reducers/users/index';

import thunkMiddleware from 'redux-thunk';
import { persistStore } from 'redux-persist';

import autoMergeLevel2 from 'redux-persist/lib/stateReconciler/autoMergeLevel2';
import { persistReducer } from 'redux-persist';

var reducers = combineReducers({
  users: users,
  ui: ui
});

export default () => {
  let store;
  const isClient = typeof window !== 'undefined';
  if (isClient) {
    var storage = require('redux-persist/lib/storage').default;
    var persistConfig = {
      key: 'root',
      storage,
      stateReconciler: autoMergeLevel2,

      whitelist: ['users', 'ui'] // place to select which state you want to persist
    };

    var persistedReducer = persistReducer(persistConfig, reducers);

    store = configureStore({
      reducer: persistedReducer,
      middleware: [thunkMiddleware, createLogger()]
    });
    store.__PERSISTOR = persistStore(store);
  } else {
    store = configureStore({
      reducer: persistedReducer,
      middleware: [thunkMiddleware, createLogger()]
    });
  }
  return store;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'd specifically recommend switching to using [the `configureStore` API from our official Redux Toolkit package](https://redux-toolkit.js.org/api/configureStore).  It already has this option turned on by default, and it will handle setting up the rest of your store with good defaults as well.

**update**

That error sounds like you're not actually passing a `reducer` field to `configureStore`.

Per your updated code, I'm pretty sure this `else` block is wrong:

```js
    store = configureStore({
      reducer: persistedReducer,
      middleware: [thunkMiddleware, createLogger()]
    });
```

Based on your logic, `persistedReducer` only exists in the `if` block, so it's `undefined` in the `else` block.

Also, your use of the `middleware` arg is currently leaving out all the automatic use of dev check middleware.

I'd suggest rewriting this as:

```js
export default () => {
  let rootReducer;
  const isClient = typeof window !== 'undefined';
  if (isClient) {
    // redux-persist setup logic here
    rootReducer = persistReducer(persistConfig, reducers);
  } else {
    rootReducer = reducers;
  }

  const store = configureStore({
    reducer: rootReducer,
     middleware: [...getDefaultMiddleware(), createLogger()]
  })

  return store
}
```

Comment: Many thanks! I dug into the issues there and found folks also using `redux-persist` but as I updated my question I am getting `Error: "reducer" is a required argument, and must be a function or an object of functions that can be passed to combineReducers`...
Any thoughts?

Comment: Wow thanks my friend! THIS is so awesome! Now with just installing the tool kit I am getting useful info about my store/state in my console. Thank you! BTW would you know what is causing this?https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61987537/redux-my-state-is-receiving-redux-initi-8-g-w-a-m-redux-state-not-updating

Comment: I don't mean to drag you down a rabbit hole, but was curious as you might have some insight... :)