# Next.js: getServerSideProps with react-redux and redux-persist

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-redux, next.js, getserversideprops

I am having a problem with my dispatchers not firing the [reducer and not updating the state](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61987537/redux-my-state-is-receiving-redux-initi-8-g-w-a-m-redux-state-not-updating) :

Figured I am not levering `getServerSideProps` correctly as the [docs](https://nextjs.org/docs/basic-features/data-fetching#when-should-i-use-getserversideprops) from next suggest, as well as [this blog post](https://dev.to/waqasabbasi/server-side-rendered-app-with-next-js-react-and-redux-38gf).

So before I go down a rabbit hole:

The point of react-redux is to have state anywhere in your app without having to prop-drill, or pass functions to a child to update the parent; And the point of using `getServerSideProps`, from the next docs:

**

> When should I use getServerSideProps?

**

> You should use getServerSideProps only if you need to pre-render a
>   page whose data must be fetched at request time. Time to first byte
>   (TTFB) will be slower than getStaticProps because the server must
>   compute the result on every request, and the result cannot be cached
>   by a CDN without extra configuration.

That being said am I wrong in thinking this will solve my problem of the redux dispatchers not having the reducer fire:

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import { connect } from 'react-redux';

import { Switch, Route, Redirect, withRouter } from 'react-router-dom';

import LinkNavWithLayout from './LinkNavWithLayout';
import Index from './home';
import Profile from './profile';
import Dashboard from './dashboard';
import ForgotPassword from './forgotPassword';
import UpdatePassword from './updatePassword';
import Login from './login';
import Confirmation from './confirmation';
import Register from './register';

class App extends Component {

  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
  }

  render() {
    const { isLoggedIn, accountNotVerified } = this.props;
    let navBars = [
      { name: 'Home', path: '/' },
      { name: 'Profile', path: '/profile' },
      { name: 'Dashboard', path: '/dashboard' },
      { name: 'Log in', path: '/login' },
      { name: 'Register', path: '/register' }
    ];

    function PrivateRoute({ children, ...rest }) {
      return (
        <Route
          {...rest}
          render={({ location }) =>
            isLoggedIn && !accountNotVerified ? (
              { ...children }
            ) : (
              <Redirect
                to={{
                  pathname: '/',
                  state: { from: location }
                }}
              />
            )
          }
        />
      );
    }

    return (
      <>
        <Switch>
          <Route
            path="/"
            isLoggedIn={isLoggedIn}
            exact
            render={props => (
              <LinkNavWithLayout {...props} data={navBars}>
                <Index />
              </LinkNavWithLayout>
            )}
          />

          <PrivateRoute path="/profile" isLoggedIn={isLoggedIn}>
            <LinkNavWithLayout data={navBars}>
              <Profile user />
            </LinkNavWithLayout>
          </PrivateRoute>

          <PrivateRoute path="/dashboard" isLoggedIn={isLoggedIn}>
            <LinkNavWithLayout data={navBars}>
              <Dashboard />
            </LinkNavWithLayout>
          </PrivateRoute>

          <Route
            path="/login"
            render={props => <Login accountNotVerified={accountNotVerified} {...props} />}
          />


          <Route path="/register" render={props => <Register {...props} />} />

          <Route
            component={({ location }) => (
              <h1>
                Sorry but the page{' '}
                <p style={{ fontWeight: 'strong' }}>{location.pathname.substring(1)} </p>{' '}
                Page, Could Not be found
              </h1>
            )}
          />
        </Switch>
      </>
    );
  }
}

export async function getServerSideProps() {
     var {isLoggedIn, accountNotVerified} = this.props
  return { props: { isLoggedIn, accountNotVerified } }; // will be passed to the page component as props
}

function mapStateToProps(state) {
  var { users } = state;
  var { isLoggedIn, accountNotVerified } = users;

  return { isLoggedIn, accountNotVerified };
}

export default withRouter(connect(mapStateToProps)(App));
```

`getServerSideProps` seems to be doing the same thing as `mapStateToProps` and all the other redux stuff. Could someone help in explaining how this works with redux? Should I just add `getServerSideProps` to my profile page (that's the page not updating, the actions are not firing ) As I am not sure why certain state in my store is getting updated?

Any help would be appreciated!